# Any, Dark for colors and Any, Light, Dark for images, why?

Tags: ios, ios13, ios-darkmode

I am adapting an existing app to dark mode.

A certain view uses an image to represent the state of a feature. I have selected the image inside the assets catalog and modified its `Appearances` field from none to `Any, Dark`. Then I added images for the `Dark` mode and nope. When I run the app, the image does not appear when the device is on `Light` mode. That forced me to change that image from `Any, Dark` to `Any, Light, Dark` and then define images for the light mode.

I had a label on the same view and I changed that view to `Any, Dark` just to check and it worked properly.

Why one view works and the other doesn't? 
Bug?

Should I change that label to `Any, Light, Dark`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the light image into `Any` if you only have light and dark.

`Any` is used in iOS 12 and below where dark mode is not yet available. If you, for instance, had a dark theme before iOS 13, then you would put all your dark assets in `Any` and `Dark` and the (new) light assets in `Light`. This way the app remains dark in iOS <= 12.

Comment: So for apps that only support iOS 13 and up, are you saying we should use Any, Dark?

Comment: Or Light and Dark, both would work. But yes, you don’t need three anymore.

Comment: I would have thought that the option would have been Light, Dark, or Any, Light, Dark. But they are Any, Dark and Any, Light, Dark. Which is what gave me pause..